# Remove Tab Panel in Google Apps Script

Tags: tabpanel, google-apps-script

I created a Tab Panel with a few tabs using the UI services of Google Apps Script, and I added to each tab a button to let the user remove that particular tab.  To the purpose, I attached to the button a server handler that should take care of this task.  However, I am unable to remove the tabs.  I tried various codes, including

`tabpanel.remove(tabnum);`

and

`tabpanel.remove(tab);`

which are known to work within GWT, but do not apparently in Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible.

Even though UiApp was built based on GWT it doesn't have all the functionality that GWT has.

Please see this [TabPanel Reference page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tabpanel) for the methods that are available for UiApp#TabPanel.

Best,
Anton